# Unicode not displaying in png

Tags: python, unicode, matplotlib

I have a function which changes an exponent from 1e+N to 1x10^N, where the N would be unicode superscripted N:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
try:
    unicode
except:
    unicode = str

_superscripts = u'⁻⁰ⁱ²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹'
_superscript_map = dict(zip(map(ord, u'-0123456789'), _superscripts))

def to_fancy(number, fmt='e'):
    as_str = ('{:' + fmt + '}').format(number)
    as_str, _, exponent = as_str.partition('e')
    if exponent:
        exponent = unicode(int(exponent.replace('+', '')))
        exponent = exponent.translate(_superscript_map)
        as_str += u'×10' + exponent
    return as_str
```

If I then plot a graph with a title, using this value i.e.:

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.title(to_fancy(1e+18))
```

The output looks fine on the xwindow (This is using the MacOSx backend).

[image: Title shows fine]

But when I save the figure in the normal manner as a .png file, it renders the unicode as empty boxes:

[image: Failed Unicode Rendering]

Comment: Presumably this is in matplotlib?

Comment: Aah yes. Sorry, knew I'd missed something.

Comment: You probably want to use the [`format()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) rather than `str.format()` here; so replace `('{:' + fmt + '}').format(number)` with `format(number, fmt)`. Much simpler.

Comment: Ah, traced that to a previous question. Took Antti to task over that one.

Comment: Done that, thank you. Yeah, I inherited that code from him.

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but why don't you use TeX formatting? Seems much simpler to do something like `result = '$'+base+'\cdot10^{'+exponent+'}$'` than to do the conversion to unicode.

Comment: I "think" (though im not sure) that another person suggested this solution because I needed it for a tickmark on an axis. Not specifically for a title. Normally I would just use TeX for titles. It's a find and replace solution for the exponents in the offest.

Comment: The OSX backend is an independent code-path from the Agg renderer which creates the png.  There is a font issue where the font used by the OSX backend has the exponent glyphs, but the one Agg is using does not.  Try explicitly setting the font to be one you know has those glyphs.

Comment: If you try this in one of the other interactive backends (tk, wx, qt) I suspect you will see the boxes again.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. If I plot using Agg or TkAgg the box appears instead of the unicode exponents. How does one explicitly set the font, and how would I know if it supports the unicode superscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a fix, thanks to the hints provided above. The simplest way to sort this is to use TeX unicode formatting. I had tried this previously, and it did not work, because of path issues, where my TeXShop distribution has decided it shouldn't install to the usual places.

Make sure that the following are in the path:

1. Ghostscript
2. kpsewhich
3. dvipng

Then set the following parameters:

```
rcParams['text.usetex']=True
rcParams['text.latex.unicode']=True
```

This is slow, and not ideal, because the font is horrible. But it at least prevents the boxes appearing in the output.